# SVG with fixed height and scaling width

Tags: css, svg

I currently have a `div` in my home page, serving as the first section of it. It has a `background-image` which is a SVG file.

What I'd like, is for the background to not move vertically when scaling it. Have it with fixed height, but scale horizontally.

Currently, I can get it to have 2 different behaviours, neither the one I want.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The first gif is closest to what I want, giving the `svg` element a `height` attribute and using `preserveAspectRatio=none`, but then the circles inside don't preserve their aspect ratio.

The second example could also work, but if the svg were clipped to the bottom of the div instead of the top. But I don't know how to make it scale "upwards" instead of downwards.

Comment: If the circles are supposed preserve their aspect ratio, that means that, pixel-for-pixel, it becomes a different image than it was before. You might be able to achieve it if you put them in a different logical layer (vague suggestion, I know).

Comment: I guess.. that's why the second gif scaling up seems like a better solution, even though not ideal.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want to have happen, but it's a background image, so you can use the background-position property set to center bottom to fix the image to the bottom of the containing element.  Also, with background-attachment set to fixed, the image won't scroll.

Comment: @jme11 thanks! `background-position` did the trick for now. What I want ideally, is that scaling only happens horizontally, the graph stretches sideways, but circles keep their circle-shape, and the graph shouldn't go higher. I just started playing around with svg :P